# How to create a temporary / dynamic / virtual table when a SQL runs in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have some data that has to be measured which are not in any table. I can not insert it to a table nor I can create any table and insert these data. So I used dual like the following to get that table. I used this to join with other tables.

```
with movie_genre as
(
select '10' as "id", 'action' as "genre" from dual
union select '20' as "id", 'horror' as "genre" from dual
union select '30' as "id", 'comedy' as "genre" from dual
union select '40' as "id", 'adventure' as "genre" from dual
union select '50' as "id", 'drama' as "genre" from dual
union select '60' as "id", 'mystery' as "genre" from dual
union select '70' as "id", 'musical' as "genre" from dual
)
select * from movie_genre
;
```

So that I get the result -

```
id  genre
10  action
20  horror
30  comedy
40  adventure
50  drama
60  mystery
70  musical
```

My question is, is there any better way to do this? Any suggestion will be a life saver.

An example -

Lets say we have a table -

```
create table movies (
id number,
name varchar2(50),
genre_id number
);

insert into movies values (1, 'the hulk', 10);
insert into movies values (2, 'dumb and dumber', 30);
insert into movies values (3, 'frozen', 70);
```

And we need a result like this -

```
name                genre        is_in_genre
the hulk            action       yes
the hulk            horror       no
the hulk            comedy       no
the hulk            adventure    no
the hulk            drama        no
the hulk            mystery      no
the hulk            musical      no
dumb and dumber     action       no
dumb and dumber     horror       no
dumb and dumber     comedy       yes
dumb and dumber     adventure    no
dumb and dumber     drama        no
dumb and dumber     mystery      no
dumb and dumber     musical      no
frozen              action       no
frozen              horror       no
frozen              comedy       no
frozen              adventure    no
frozen              drama        no
frozen              mystery      no
frozen              musical      yes
```

Here, we DO NOT have any movie_genre table.

Comment: Please describe which task you tried to solve. Your approach is typical for debugging or sampling purposes, while we need some data to make and check the query. There are number of techniques which can be used for the other purposes.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a table for the genres?

Comment: Because I am not permitted to do so. The movie genre list is in the java code, not in database. @ZeissS

Comment: Then do the mapping / stuff in Java? Fetch the genreID and replace it there with value from your genre-list.

Comment: Or create a temporary table and generate it on every app-start.

Comment: *" I can not insert it to a table nor I can create any table and insert these data. "* - Why?

Comment: well, truly speaking the tables / data that I used here is only for example. The main database that I am working on contains protected health information which cant be put in the db. But, the scenario is pretty similar, so I used this movie example. @GolezTrol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the genre as string in the order you want and use regular expression to generate the movie_genre table.The [sql fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/1736)

```
with movie_genre as
( 
 select level * 10 as id, regexp_substr(genre,'[^,]+',1,level) as genre
 from
 (
  select ('action,horror,comedy,adventure,drama,mystery,musical') 
  as genre from dual
  )
  connect by level <=REGEXP_COUNT(genre,'[^,]+')
 )
 select * from movie_genre;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get the full list, you want a `cross join`, with some additional logic:

```
with movie_genre as (
      select '10' as "id", 'action' as "genre" from dual union all
      select '20' as "id", 'horror' as "genre" from dual union all
      select '30' as "id", 'comedy' as "genre" from dual union all
      select '40' as "id", 'adventure' as "genre" from dual union all
      select '50' as "id", 'drama' as "genre" from dual union all
      select '60' as "id", 'mystery' as "genre" from dual union all
      select '70' as "id", 'musical' as "genre" from dual
     )
select m.name, mg.genre,
       (case when m.genre_id = mg.id then 'yes' else 'no' end) as IsInGenre
from movies m cross join
     movie_genres mg;
```

Comment: yes, I know that, I also solved the query. It can be done by either using cross join or partition clause.

But my question is, is there a better way of creating that 'movie_genre' table by using dual and union like that? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @SamiulAlHossaini . . . I think clarity is very important when writing queries.  If you need such a lookup table, you should have it in the database.  If not, creating it in a clear and obvious way is the next best choice.

Comment: Hi, what do you think about my answer? is it faster than unioning dual?
@Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this works for Oracle, but for SQL Server there is a neater implementation.

Example: SELECT a, b FROM (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10) ) AS MyTable(a, b);

Ref:
Section C. Specifying multiple values as a derived table in a FROM clause

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

Thus you can use DECODE function. Something like this:

```
select 
  m.*,
  decode(m.genre_id, 10, 'action', 20, 'horror', ...) as genre
from 
  movies m
```

If you wish to generate you strange formed resultset, you can use, say

```
select
  m.name,
  decode(n.id, 10, 'Action', ...) genre,
  case when m.genre_id = n.id then 'yes' else 'no' end is_in_genre
from
  movies m,
  (select 10 * rownum id from dual connect by level <= 7) n
```

More common way is to eliminate movies_genre at all:

```
select
  m.name,
  case when m.genre_id = 10 then 'yes' else 'no' end is_action,
  case when m.genre_id = 20 then 'yes' else 'no' end is_horror,
  ....
from
  movies m
from
  movies m,
  (select 10 * rownum id from dual connect by level <= 7) n
```

Comment: Nope ... I tried. You will get matched genre but not all the genre.

Comment: For matching 'all the genre' you're in need of cross join as answered by @Gordon. But commenting his answer you're asking about this :)

Answer (score 0):

The `movie_genre` table can also be created by the following -

```
with movie_genre as
(
  select i, genre
  from 
  ( select '1000' id, 'length-of-the-longest-value' genre from dual )
  where id <> 1000
  model
  dimension by (genre)
  measures (id i)
  rules
  (
    i['action'] = 10,
    i['horror'] = 20,
    i['comedy'] = 30,
    i['adventure'] = 40,
    i['drama'] = 50,
    i['mystery'] = 60,
    i['musical'] = 70
  )
  order by i
)
select * from movie_genre;
```

What do you think about this??
Is it more efficient than doing union on all the dual tables?